# Compile Bootstrap 4 SASS in ASP Core Project for changing base font-size

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gruntjs, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-4

Actually I just wanted to change the base font-size of Bootstrap 4, after my research I found the customary solution would be to override the variables via it's `_custom.scss`, which I did by `$font-size-root: 14px;`, so far so good.

Now Bootstrap 4 website says I should recompile my sass... alright, after googling and testing many tutorials nothing really did the trick for me.
To be frank, I'm not a web developer. I come from C# and wanted to play around with MVC6 and here I am.

So I have my Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with the ASP.NET Core Web Application project which was the original project template provided by Microsoft, I just changed it to use Bootstrap 4 as a bower dependency. 
Giving me a `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap` with a `Gruntfile.js` and a `package.json`.

How can I get my `_custom.scss`to be recompiled to a new `\dist\css\boostrap.css` with the least amount of tooling and stuff. I mean since there is a gruntfile already, I feel like everything is already there, I just don't know how to execute the `Gruntfile.js`.

I tried `Task Runner Explorer` with `NPM Task Runner`, then `Grunt Launcher` they all don't seem to work with the nested wwwroot ... So is there any way to easily get this done, or am I the first person that is doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it to work the hard way after even more research, but I would like to know if that's really the way it's supposed to be? I did found the various steps here and there so I am not sure exactly if they are all necessary, but never touch a running build system ;)))

Anyway here is what was necessary to get from my `_custom.scss` to a fresh `bootstrap.css`:

1. Download and install Ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/

   - Download the installer
   - Run the installer, don't forget to check the option to set the PATH variable to Ruby's executable
2. Install Ruby Development Kit from http://rubyinstaller.org/

   - Download the archive regarding the version you just installed (1.x.x / 2.x.x, 32-bit / 64-bit)
   - Extract the Archive into your ruby installation folder: `<RubyInstallationFolder>\DevKit`
   - Open a console (cmd.exe) in that folder and execute the following:

     - `ruby dk.rb init`
     - `ruby dk.rb review`
     - `ruby dk.rb install`
3. Then install sass, bundler and scss lint, still in the console via:

   - `gem install sass`
   - `gem install bundler`
   - `gem update --system && gem install scss-lint`
4. Install the Visual Studio extension "Grunt Launcher" via:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaoloNicodemo.GruntLauncher
5. Open your solution and edit the your Bootstrap grunt file

   - open `~\lib\bootstrap\Gruntfile.js`
   - add after the last registerTask the line `grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-sass");`
   - also if you are using the default Bootstrap4 bundle, there is qunit task that will stop Grunt due to a warning, you have to add the force option, so you end up with:

     `qunit: {
         options: {
             force: true,
             inject: 'js/tests/unit/phantom.js'
         },
         files: 'js/tests/index.html'
     },`
6. Now at last you can execute your Grunt file:

   - right-click on your bootstrap `Gruntfile.js -> Grunt -> Grunt`
   - Switch your output window to `Grunt execution` to see the status
   - and now you should have an updated `bootstrap.css` with the `font-size: 14px`

Comment: When you say "right-click on your bootstrap Gruntfile.js -> Grunt -> Grunt" where exactly am I clicking on it? I dont have any VS solution. Should I create one? If yes, what kind of project should I have?

Comment: I had an ASP.NET Core Project, which is just a .json file (at least pre-VS2017). I guess you could create an empty .NET Core project and do the same. Though I'm sure there is a way to execute Grunt without VS then. So if you install Grunt outside of VS you could just execute it from there, but I haven't done that. I wanted a solution "inside" of VS.

Comment: Yes, I have created a solution and added Gruntfile.js to it. when I run it I get:Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
I also ran this from the command line:

npm install -g grunt-cli

Still the same. What am I  missing?

Comment: grunt-cli is not grunt, you also need npm install grunt if it's not already installed.

Comment: I ran npm install grunt but the message in VS is still the same when I run the task.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out :/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Web Essentials for Visual Studio? I use it with VS2017 with bootstrap 3.x sass. All I have to do is right mouse on _bootstrap.sass and then select Web Compiler -> Compile. You'll have to point to the new file or copy to /dist using another mechanism.

http://vswebessentials.com/